# How to limit ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, arraylist

In my application, I want to get some `list` from **server** and show in app, but I want set **limited** this list and just **show last 2 items**. I don't want to show all list, I want show **just 2 item**.

For get list from server with this code:

```
List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<>();
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;
mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();

for (String str : mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings) {
    cloudChipList.clear();
    cloudChipList.add(str);
    if (cloudChipList.size() > 0) {
        fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChip(str);
    }
    count++;
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Create new list, copy just 2 items into it, then pas it to list adapter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the last two items in the String array mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings, then it is for example:

```
String lastStrItem= mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings [mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length-1];

String secondToLastStrItem= mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings [mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length-2];
```

If you need them added to cloudChipList then you can use the following:

```
cloudChipList.add( mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings [mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length-1])

cloudChipList.add( mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings [mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings.length-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#pop()) (you really just need some kind of **stack** implementation) instead of an `ArrayList`, and call `pop()` twice to get the last two elements. If you already have a `List`, then you can convert it to an `ArrayDeque` by passing the `List` as a constructor argument:

```
final ArrayDeque<String> arrDeque = new ArrayDeque<>(listOfStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link for basics of an  [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

You cannot directly assign list of items to an Array dynamically. Please correct you code.

Method 1: 
If it is an Array you can get the last 2 items by passing index position like

```
String[] anArray;

    // allocates memory for 10 integers
    anArray = new String[10];
    //get last 2 items 
    System.out.println("Element at index last position: "+ anArray[9]);
    System.out.println("Element at index last but one position: "+ anArray[8]);
```

Method 2: If it is ArrayList ,you can add dynamically like below

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();
System.out.println("Element at index last position: "+ arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-1);
System.out.println("Element at index last but one position: "+ arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-2);
```